# How to extract all links (relative and absolute) from a webpage using Java?

Tags: java, url, jsoup, html

I am trying to extract and display all the links on a webpage using jSoup:

```
Document doc =   Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/").get();
   Elements links = doc.select("link");
    Elements scripts = doc.select("script");
   for (Element element : links) {
         System.out.println("href:" + element.absUrl("href"));
   }
   for (Element element : scripts) {
         System.out.println("src:" + element.absUrl("src"));
```

This is my code. It is working without errors however, it is not giving me ALL the links, rather, only a few. And many of the src elements are being outputted as blank. Here is the output:

```
herehref:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-core-vfluKFg1a.css
here`href:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-home-c4-vfl4p1Pju.css
href:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-pageframe-vflfdzMKI.css
href:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-guide-vflTkT47C.css
href:http://www.youtube.com/opensearch?locale=en_US
href:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon-vfldLzJxy.ico
href:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_32-vflWoMFGx.png
href:http://www.youtube.com/
href:https://m.youtube.com/?
href:https://m.youtube.com/?
href:https://plus.google.com/115229808208707341778
src:
src:
src:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-scheduler-vflNAje0j/www-scheduler.js
src:
src:
src:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/spf-vfld6zcp2/spf.js
src:https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-en_US-vflLgbz4u/base.js
src:
src:
```

Please tell me why this is happening and how to rectify it?

Comment: What output did you expect and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting all the `link` elements when you instead want to select all the hyperlinks through the `a` element.

The blank output of the `script` elements is due to the fact that some of the elements are not pointing to external script sources with the `src` attribute, but instead holds inline javascript statements.

You can use a different selector to get the `src` of those elements that have that attribute, just like below.

```
//Get the document
Document doc =   Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/").get();

//Get all the hyperlinks
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
//Loop through them
for (Element element : links) {
     System.out.println("href: " + element.absUrl("href"));
}

//Get all script elements with src
Elements scriptSources = doc.select("[src]");
//Loop through them
for (Element element : scriptSources) {
     System.out.println("src:" + element.absUrl("src"));
}
```